# If Else outputting same result

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Sorry to bother you all again, but I seem to have another problem with my code. It's outputting the same result for some input and I've spent the last 15 or so minutes trying to find out what the problem is. I'd ask my instructor but I;m not in Uni at the present.

Again, code is below, and thanks for taking the time to put up with me.

```
//declare vars and/or constants
var endString = "Total cost per night is $";

//input vars
pplCount = prompt("How many people will be staying?");
discYes = prompt("Do you have an AAA discount?");
viewYes = prompt("Do you want a room with a view?");

//if variables
//double yes

if(pplCount == "1" || pplCount == "2" && discYes == "Yes" && viewYes == "Yes") {
    discount = 50*0.15;
    roomCost = 50;
    viewCost = (roomCost*0.10);
    finalRoomCost = roomCost - discount + viewCost;
    document.write(endString + finalRoomCost);
}
else if(pplCount === "3" || pplCount === "4" && discYes == "Yes" && viewYes == "Yes") {
    discount = 60*0.10;
    roomCost = 60;
    viewCost = (roomCost*0.10);
    finalRoomCost = roomCost - discount + viewCost;
    document.write(endString + finalRoomCost);
}
else if(pplCount === "5" || pplCount === "6" && discYes === "Yes" && viewYes === "Yes") {
    discount = 70*0.05;
    roomCost = 70;
    viewCost = (roomCost*0.10);
    finalRoomCost = roomCost - discount + viewCost;
    document.write(endString + finalRoomCost);
}
else if(pplCount === "1" || pplCount === "2" && discYes === "No" && viewYes === "Yes") {
    discount = 50*0.15;
    roomCost = 50;
    viewCost = (roomCost*0.10);
    finalRoomCost = roomCost + viewCost;
    document.write(endString + finalRoomCost);
}
else if(pplCount === "3" || pplCount === "4" && discYes === "No" && viewYes === "Yes") {
    discount = 60*0.10;
    roomCost = 60;
    viewCost = (roomCost*0.10);
    finalRoomCost = roomCost + viewCost;
    document.write(endString + finalRoomCost);
}
else if(pplCount === "5" || pplCount === "6" && discYes === "No" && viewYes === "Yes") {
    discount = 70*0.05;
    roomCost = 70;
    viewCost = (roomCost*0.10);
    finalRoomCost = roomCost + viewCost;
    document.write(endString + finalRoomCost);
}
else if(pplCount === "1" || pplCount === "2" && discYes === "No" && viewYes === "No") {
    finalRoomCost = 50;
    document.write(endString + finalRoomCost);
}
else if(pplCount === "3" || pplCount === "4" && discYes === "No" && viewYes === "No") {
    finalRoomCost = 60;
    document.write(endString + finalRoomCost);
}
else if(pplCount === "5" || pplCount === "6" && discYes === "No" && viewYes === "No") {
    finalRoomCost = 70;
    document.write(endString + finalRoomCost);
}
else if(pplCount === "1" || pplCount === "2" && discYes === "Yes" && viewYes === "No") {
    discount = 50*0.15;
    roomCost = 50;
    viewCost = (roomCost*0.10);
    roomCost = roomCost - discount;
    document.write(endString + finalRoomCost);
}
else if(pplCount === "3" || pplCount === "4" && discYes === "Yes" && viewYes === "No") {
    discount = 60*0.10;
    roomCost = 60;
    finalRoomCost = roomCost - discount;
    document.write(endString + finalRoomCost);
}
else if(pplCount === "5" || pplCount === "6" && discYes === "Yes" && viewYes === "No") {
    discount = 70*0.05;
    roomCost = 70;
    finalRoomCost = roomCost - discount;
    document.write(endString + finalRoomCost);
}
```

Comment: It'd really help if you told use exactly which if-else pair is causing you problems.

Comment: Just wondering, but why are you switching between using `==` and `===`. Probably stick with `===`.

Comment: give us a use case that's failing...

Comment: `}else if(pplCount == 5 || pplCount == 6 && discYes === "Yes" &&  viewYes === "Yes") {
    discount = 70*0.05;
    roomCost = 70;
    viewCost = (roomCost*0.10);
    finalRoomCost = roomCost - discount + viewCost;
    document.write(endString + finalRoomCost);`

I found the error, it's in this block of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess there is some problem with grouping your conditions. so check your conditions like this below, i think it may solve your issue.

```
if((pplCount === "1" || pplCount === "2") && (discYes === "Yes" && viewYes === "Yes")) 
{
......
......
}
else if()
{
}
```

Comment: @minecraftModder see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/XAsX3/) is working. I just used a single else if from your code for demonstrate the working condition. But you should do this for all of your if/elseif conditions.

Answer (score 2):

The `&&` operator binds more tightly than `||`, which means that

```
if(pplCount == "1" || pplCount == "2" && discYes == "Yes" && viewYes == "Yes") {
```

is interpreted as

```
if(pplCount == "1" || ((pplCount == "2" && discYes == "Yes") && viewYes == "Yes")) {
```

Thus, that branch of the logic will be taken when "pplCount" is 1, regardless of the values of "discYes" and "viewYes".

It's like ordinary algebraic conventions (paper and pencil, forget JavaScript), where multiplication takes precedence over addition.  When you write

```
2x + 5
```

then everybody knows you mean "multiply x by 2, then add 5" instead of "add five to x, then multiply that by 2".

Comment: (y) Good description to a student than just saying _look into operator precedence_